# Insert commas between words in a string in Python

Tags: python

I just want to put commas as separators of words in a Python string, in which each word is enclosed by quotes.
My input can be: "some" "words" "but" "no" "commas"
and I would like to have a string like this: "some", "words", "but", "no", "commas"

so the last word will not have the comma at its end. Thank you in advance!

Comment: So you would like to use `","` to `.join(` a list of `words` obtained by `.split())`ing a string on spaces?

Comment: You've described a `list` of words

Answer (score 5):

```
txt = '"some" "words" "but" "no" "commas"'
commas_added = ', '.join(txt.split())
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you expecting something like this? (python 2.7.5)

```
input1 = "some"
input2 = "words"

output = "\"" + input1 + "\",\"" + input2 + "\""
output
'"some","words"'
```